# How to select a value out of a Dropdown list with span class?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I´m trying to select an item out of the dropdown list which is on the page. I couldn´t identifier the ID or something else which I could take to make this work.
I tried several thinks but I got everytime an error.

[[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpYd1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvO1F.png)

The picture will show the code where the Dropdown List is.

I tried this before but I could not click any item of the dropdown..:

```
cy.get('#select2-usd1-results').eq(2).click()
```

Or I tried this one but this is only open the dropdown list:

```
cy.get("#gwt-uid-4").click()
```

It should choose any value of the dropdown list first of all

By using the answer from agoff I got this error:

[[error_select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpIbl.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpIbl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add `{force:true}` option to overcome the error "is being covered by another element".

This turns off actionability checks such as another element covering, the element itself being hidden or disabled.

```js
cy.get('select[data-select2-id="1"]')
  .select('Government', {force:true})
```

Ref: [select command arguments](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select#Arguments)

> Forces the action, disables waiting for actionability

Answer (score 1):

[For `select` components, you can use `cy.select()` to select an option.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select#Examples)

```js
cy.get('#gwt-uid-4') // yields the div element
  .find('select') // yields the select element
  .select(2); // selects the option at index 2
  // or, you could select the element by value
  // .select('3') // selects the option with a value of '3'
  // alternatively, you could select by text content
  // .select('Company'); // select the option with a textContent of 'Company'
```

Comment: I got an error again, I'll add the picture for the error description to my post